# Use ref inside React.memo

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`React.memo` can be used to control whether a React function component should update or not. It compares by props by default. Now I want to compare a prop with one of the ref inside the function component. To be more specific, here is the code(Written in Typescript):

```js
interface RichEditorProps {
    value: string;
    onChange: (value: string) => void;
}

export const RichEditor = React.memo((props: RichEditorProps) => {

    const contentEditableDiv = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        contentEditableDiv.current!.addEventListener("input", () => {
            props.onChange(contentEditableDiv.current!.innerHTML);
        });
    });

    return (
        <div contentEditable suppressContentEditableWarning ref={contentEditableDiv}>
            {props.value}
        </div>
    )
}, ((prevProps, nextProps) => {
    // I want to do this, but it doesn't work because contentEditableDiv is not available here.
    return nextProps.value !== contentEditableDiv.current!.innerHTML;
}));
```

As you can see, I want to update the component when `contentEditableDiv.current!.innerHTML` doesn't equal to `nextProps.value`, but I cannot do it because `contentEditableDiv` is not available there. Is there any other way to achieve this without turning it into a class Component?

P.S. One way to achieve this may be to give the `div` an id and use `document.getElementById` to grab the `div` component inside the compare function. But I want to avoid this approach since in this way, I have to think of a method to assign a unique id to it, I haven't found an easy way to do it. And I'm curious if there's any other way to do it.

Comment: Why do you want to use `React.memo` in the first place? Compare it with the "current" value (before rerender) using `prevProps.value` no?

Comment: @gpichot `prevProps.value` doesn't equal to `contentEditableDiv.current!.innerHTML`. For example, at first the div is empty, then the user inputs a letter `A`. In this case, `prevProps.value` is empty, `nextProps.value` is `A`, `contentEditableDiv.current!.innerHTML` is `A`. Since `nextProps.value` equals `contentEditableDiv.current!.innerHTML`, I don't want to update this component in this case. I cannot do that with `prevProps.value`.

Comment: You didn't answer my first question, which is I think the most important. Did you try to use `React.forwardRef` ? You may want to use a `wrapper component` in this case if you don't want to have to set a ref every time you need to use your RichEditor.